"day and hour" vs "hour" - atomic expression or do components have meaning?
This is only about the Greek language itself.
Matthew 24

36“But concerning that day and hour no one knows, not even the angels
of heaven, nor the Son,b but the Father only


Περὶ δὲ τῆς ἡμέρας ἐκείνης καὶ ὥρας οὐδεὶς οἶδεν, οὐδὲ οἱ ἄγγελοι τῶν
οὐρανῶν οὐδὲ ὁ υἱός, εἰ μὴ ὁ πατὴρ μόνος


44Therefore you also must be ready, for the Son of Man is coming at an
hour you do not expect.


διὰ τοῦτο καὶ ὑμεῖς γίνεσθε ἕτοιμοι, ὅτι ᾗ οὐ δοκεῖτε ὥρᾳ ὁ Υἱὸς τοῦ
ἀνθρώπου ἔρχεται.


50the master of that servant will come on a day when he does not
expect him and at an hour he does not know


ἥξει ὁ κύριος τοῦ δούλου ἐκείνου ἐν ἡμέρᾳ ᾗ οὐ προσδοκᾷ καὶ ἐν ὥρᾳ ᾗ
οὐ γινώσκει,

Matthew 25

13Watch therefore, for you know neither the day nor the hour.


Γρηγορεῖτε οὖν, ὅτι οὐκ οἴδατε τὴν ἡμέραν οὐδὲ τὴν ὥραν.

QUESTIONS

What is day and hour?
a) the literal day and literal hour
b) an atomic expression that emphasizes the degree of uncertainty
Given day and hour was used in v36, what would be the purpose - linguistically - of only using the phrase hour subsequently . . .
. . . to be followed by the full day and hour?


Could this be influenced by some reflexion of Hebrew idiom?

There doesn't seem to be a different usage here than the usual ones in our daily speech. Suppose I say
"Of course, I shall die one day as anybody will, but only Gods knows the day and the hour of it."
Hence, there is something about the existence of which we have no doubt (that's definite), but no clear idea of its definite characterisation, either (a situation mathematicians and philosophers are much familiar with).
So, if there is any uncertainty/indefiniteness, it is for my knowledge; I do not know the date/time which God knows.
Furthermore, it is not an exceptional usage to omit the article in "adverbial designation of time" as in

καὶ εἶπεν Μωυσῆς τάδε λέγει κύριος περὶ μέσας νύκτας ἐγὼ εἰσπορεύομαι
εἰς μέσον Αἰγύπτου·
So Moses said, "This is what the Lord says: 'About midnight I will
go throughout Egypt.

